# When a copy of firefox is started another copy of firefox starts as well, why?

Tags: firefox, memory, browser, crash, multiple-instances

I am running 50.0 firefox on my windows system. I noticed that when I run a copy of a firefox, it automatically starts another instance of firefox. First instance's memory usage is around 100,000kb and the second instance's memory usage is around 50,000kb. I also noticed that when I kill the second instance, firefox tells me this webpage is CRASHED. What is going on? Is this because my computer has virus or malware, etc, etc?

Answer (score 0):

One may be viral. Use your Task Manager to make sure the full path for each is to the correct Firefox program folder. If one of them is running from a different location run a full virus scan of your computer.

Another reason is that Firefox has been planning to go to a multi-process model, like Google Chrome, for some time. It began rolling out these feature in version 48: https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2016/08/02/whats-next-for-multi-process-firefox/